# OpenVPN on Tomato and Vista - can't see my network

Tags: networking, windows-vista, vpn, openvpn

I followed the instructions here (http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.ca/2011/03/quick-simple-vpn-setup-guide-using.html) to set up a TCP connection to OpenVPN on my Tomato router. Used TCP because the place I usually surf at seems to have the other ports blocked.

My Vista laptop is able to connect to the router but I don't appear to be getting an IP address. I'm able to access my router's admin page, but I can't see the network at home. When I browse to Whatsmyip I see my home IP.

Here are the results of route print -4 when I'm just connect to the library and when I've fired up the VP connection as well:

Library only:

```
=========================================================================== 
Interface List
 22 ...00 ff c4 a0 e7 5c ...... TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
 15 ...00 23 4e 20 b3 64 ...... Atheros AR9281 Wireless Network Adapter
 10 ...00 23 8b 39 ec 71 ...... Marvell Yukon 88E8040T PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1
 11 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{834A8A0A-5E2C-47D0-9673-7965DE8B5470}
 14 ...02 00 54 55 4e 01 ...... Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 17 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 20 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  6TO4 Adapter
 18 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  6TO4 Adapter
 19 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  6TO4 Adapter
 23 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  isatap.{C4A0E75C-765E-4F7D-A55C-77945779816A}
 34 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0  Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.1.29.1      10.1.29.117     25
        10.1.29.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
      10.1.29.117  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
      10.1.29.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
===========================================================================
```

Library and TCP OpenVPN:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.1.29.1      10.1.29.117     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.116     30
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.116     30
        10.1.29.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
      10.1.29.117  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
      10.1.29.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
    24.212.205.68  255.255.255.255        10.1.29.1      10.1.29.117     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.116     30
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.116    286
    192.168.1.116  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.116    286
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.116    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.116    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.116    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.29.117    281
===========================================================================
```

Thanks for any advice. I looked at one of the answers but I'm not sure if it applied to me as it said that 10.*.*.* was the vpn connection, but I appear to have 10.*.*.* when I connect just to the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tomato VPN Server -> Advanced! Check "Push LAN to clients" option.

Comment: just looked and there isn't that option under the advanced tab

Comment: In that case you will have to add it manually in you're server.cong with:
push "route local_subnet mask"

You can do this in the "Custom Configuration" or just ssh into the router and do it in the shell

Comment: thanks. Still new to some of the terminology. How do I determine what my local subnet is in Tomato? Thanks.

Comment: If the router's ip is 192.168.1.1 I would say its 192.168.1.0 netmask beign 255.255.255.0
But you should have a menu that shows tomato's routing table.